# Need a word similar to 'slight difference' but its not really in the 'slight' to 'medium' range

Tags: single-word-requests

The word probably is in the 'slight' to 'none'  range.

Scenario is I have a pie chart. 
Majority is 55 percent, secondary is 40 percent and I need to compare the majority to the secondary.

Comment: I don’t understand.  You’re saying the difference between 40 and 55% is slight to none??!

Comment: @Jim Not really it. I need a word that describes the diffrence of the two shares which are 55 and 40, the word probably exists in the range of the words 'slight' to 'none' since I think the two words denote range. For example, I say 'I need to go to school' another person could either say 'The distance from here to the school is not that far'  which is in the none's meaning or 'The distance from here to the school is slightly far' which is in the slight's meaning .

Comment: **4 in 10** *blah, blah*.... Whilst an impressive **40 percent** *blah blah*... **lagging behind** with just 40%

Comment: Yes, but in the world of percents, there is a quite a difference between 40 and 55%- around 27%.   Not small.  If you think it’s small to none, can I borrow $550 and I will pay you back $400.  :-)

Comment: *Not that far* does not mean *none*. And *slightly far* doesn't really make any sense. I can think of a word that is between *slight and none*, but I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, because I can't really understand your examples.

Comment: A word for a difference in the 'slight to none' range would be _infinitesimal_, but, as others have said, the difference between 40 and 55% is not infinitesimal.

Comment: Don't understand either, but perhaps with your 'not that far' example you are looking for a negated phrase, e.g. 'not inconsiderable difference'.

Comment: 40% of a population is a _substantial minority_.

Answer (score -1):

The less than 50% is called a *Minority*. The 40% group is the *Minority* in contrast to the majority. This is a use of minor in contrast to major.

Since they are nearly equal they can be called the bare minority. As in they are just barely missing the "goal" of being a majority.